# How to get the distinct keys from JSOB fast?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following PostgreSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    order_date timestamp without time zone,
    data jsonb
);
```

I need to get a set of distinct keys from json. The following straight-forward query does the job but it's extremely slow because it fulfills a Seq Scan:

```
select
 distinct(jsonb_object_keys(orders.data))
from
 orders
```

How I can utilize an index?

Comment: "*because it fulfills a Seq Scan*" - well, it needs to look at **all** rows of the table and the most efficient way to do that is to do a Seq Scan. If you need to do this a lot, you might ask yourself if properly normalizing the data would be a better approach

Comment: Thank you. I played with structures and indexes a bit (including old good btree over normalized data) and it still does a seq scan. So it looks like there is no quick solution for this task, existing algorithms can't identify ranges and have to iterate everything :).